# How can a factor in front of a sum sign be integrated into the sum sign?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation

I am working on a recurrence equation and I am wondering why this equivalence? What's the general rule to do this for other sums?

$$T(\frac{5^k}{5^k})+4·5^k\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac {1}{5^i}\right)+k = T(1)+4·5\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 5^i+k $$

Comment: The right hand is obtained from the left through routine algebra.  $\frac {5^k}{5^k}=1$, for example.

Comment: Think of it like a change of variables. The $5^{k-1}$ goes inside the summation sign and it becomes $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 5^{k-1-i}$. Now do a change of variable $t \rightarrow k-1-i$

Comment: @Lulu yes that is clear, the question is about the sum

Comment: @Nikunj What do you mean by change of variable and where does t appear on the RHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$5^k\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac {1}{5^i}\right) = 5^k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac1{5^{ (k-1)-i}}=5^k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{5^{-k+1+i}}=5\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 5^i$$

Comment: What do the brackets mean exactly, i.e. why is $5^k\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac {1}{5^i}\right) = 5^k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac1{5^{ (k-1)-I}}$?

Comment: @david just expand both of the sums. You will see that both are same but the one on the rhs is just inverted. Brackets don't play any role here.